# Java code error linked list

Tags: java, static, linked-list

Hi it's been a while since I've written java and I can't seem to find what is wrong with this code. I'm implenting deleting a node from a linked list but my program won't compile. I keep getting: 
error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

```
Node head = new Node();
```

It has an error for all my new Node() instances in my main method.

```
public class NodeDelete{

 class Node {
 int data;
 Node next;

    public Node(){ }
}


Node Delete(Node head, int position) {
    // Complete this method
        int index = 0;
        Node current = head;
        if (position == 0 ){
            head = head.next;               
        }
        else{
            while (index < (position - 1)){ 
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = current.next.next;
        }
        return head;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node head = new Node();
        head.data = 0;

        Node node1 = new Node();
        node1.data = 1;

        Node node2 = new Node(); 
        node2.data = 2;

        head.next = node1;
        node1.next = node2;           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Either** make the `Node` class static. **OR** take out `Node` class from the `NodeDelete` class. That will solve the issue.

The `Node` class is a **non-static** inner class of `NodeDelete`, so it is like a member of the `NodeDelete` class. To access any member in the static context, instance of the class is required. That is why you are getting the **compile time error** here.

**Note :** The constructor you have defined in the `Node` is same as the default constructor. So no need to define it. It is redundant.

Making Node class static:

```
static class Node {
  int data;
  Node next;

  public Node(){  }  // This is same as the default constructor. So this can be remove.
}
```

**OR**

Take out the same implementation from the NodeDelete class.

Answer (score 0):

`Node` is a non-static inner class. Therefore a instance of the containing class is needed to construct the instance:

```
NodeDelete nd = ...
Node node = nd.new Node();
```

#### Alternatives:

- Make `Node` a static inner class
- Make `Node` a top level class

Since there is no reference to a `NodeDelete` in `Node`'s methods I recommend making `Node` static.

Answer (score 0):

Another option not given yet, though not my favorite, would be to instantiate an instance of the class which contains the main method then use it to instantiate the inner class. Like so...

```
NodeDelete nd = new NodeDelete(...);
Node n = nd.new Node(...);
```